# how to know the number of child elements in js?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a parent `<div>` that contains multiple `<h2>` elements inside.
How to know the number of `<h2>` elements inside this parent?
And how to locate every single `<h2>` element in this parent without using `id` or `class`?

Comment: [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) method to retrieve all the `h2` elements within the `div` and then use the `length` property to find out the number of `h2` elements like this:

```js
const headers = document.querySelectorAll('div h2');

alert(headers.length);
```

```html
<div>
  <h2>A</h2>
  <h2>B</h2>
  <h2>C</h2>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your container div has the id `container`, you can query for the children like so:

```js
document.getElementById("container").querySelectorAll('h2')
```